# How to flash Arduino code into Arduino with Java

Tags: java, arduino

How can I flash C++ code into an Arduino using Java? The Arduino I am using is a Mega 2560 and I need to be able to flash it from a raspberry pi.

If you can, please include code examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With proper connectivity you ca use the [OTA library](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/libraries/arduinoota/) to update the bin file.

Use Arduino IDE to create a bin file of your program, move it to the storage and OTA it from there.